# IllegalArgumentException:Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
public int compareTo(LelinkServiceInfoWrapper o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return 0;
    }
    // 1. 判断是否在线
    if (isOnLine() == o.isOnLine()) {
        // 2. 判断是否常用
        if (isFavorite == o.isFavorite) {
            // 3. 判断是否是同一wifi
            // 判断Lelink或DLNA是否在线来判断

            // 3. 判断是否有uid
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(this.uid) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(o.uid)) {
                return 0;
            } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(this.uid) && TextUtils.isEmpty(o.uid)) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return !TextUtils.isEmpty(this.uid) ? -1 : 1;
            }
        } else {
            return isFavorite ? -1 : 1;
        }
    } else {
        return isOnLine() ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

isOnLine is boolean value,uid is a String value.
and this exception stack trace,How can I solve this?:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Comparison method violates its general contract!
java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeHi(ComparableTimSort.java:866)
java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt(ComparableTimSort.java:483)
java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeCollapse(ComparableTimSort.java:406)
java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:213)
java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1251)
java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1426)
java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.sort(Arrays.java:3823)
java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:201)
java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:156)
com.hpplay.sdk.source.browse.impl.BrowserManager$a.a(SourceFile:524)
com.hpplay.sdk.source.browse.impl.BrowserManager$a.a(SourceFile:502)
com.hpplay.sdk.source.browse.impl.BrowserManager$a.serviceAlive(SourceFile:452)
com.hpplay.sdk.source.browse.handler.a.c(SourceFile:117)
com.hpplay.sdk.source.browse.handler.a.run(SourceFile:71)
```

why does this code throw an exception, "Comparison method violates its general contract!", and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include how you call `compareTo()`, the error and the stack trace?

Comment: What is the definition of the `isOnLine()` method?

Comment: Please post error stack trace and code which you invoking as well.

Comment: This error means that in your list you have a comparaison A == B and then B == C and then C != A, check your isOnline method and be sure that A == B and B == A.